# Insert ProfileLoginIpRange field's data in salesforce using PHP

Tags: apex, metadata-api, metadata

I want to insert ProfileLoginIpRange field's data in salesforce using PHP. So How can i do through PHP. So that whenever insert ip's from php, it should get updated in salesforce. Please Help me out.

Comment: VT Please explain why you're not sure how to do this. All your questions have been very broad and show no effort of your own nor explain us what you're having trouble with.

Comment: hurrey here is the answer. And make a change into meta.xml file. Put this lines in meta.xml file under profile tag. <xsd:element name="loginIpRanges" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="tns:ProfileLoginIpRange"/>   https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2011/11/extending-the-force-com-toolkit-for-php-to-handle-the-metadata-api.html

Comment: Vt, you could post that as an actual answer. That way you could also accept it as such to mark the question as solved.

Comment: Samuel De Rycke, i am unable post answer. yes,this is an actual answer.

Comment: VT I've reopend the question, so that you can post that as an answer. That way    your efforts can help others in the future and they'll have an easier time finding the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hurrey here is the answer. And make a change into meta.xml file. Put this lines in meta.xml file under profile tag.  
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2011/11/extending-the-force-com-toolkit-for-php-to-handle-the-metadata-api.html